# Vue Axios - Display frontend results?

Tags: vue.js, axios

How can I display frontend results.The data is showing in the console.log but not in the frontend. I need help.

HTML

```
<b-card class="mt-3" header="Patient Information">
        
        <p>Name {{this.patientName}} </p>
     
        <br><br>
          <div class="graphtitle">Medical Record</div>
   </b-card>
```

Script

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
data():{},
methods: {
   getPatient(){
            
        axios.get('https://xxx/medicalRecord/api/v1/getMedicalRecord?patientID=s3333333c')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.patientName = response.data.message.patientName;
                        
                        console.log(response.data.message);
                    })
                    .catch(error => alert(error));
    
        }
}
}
```

Comment: console log `this.patientName` instead of `response.data.message` to make sure `response.data.message.patientName` is defined

Comment: Might try to add an `async` in front of `getPatient(){` as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your template, you don’t need the `this`. Change it to:

```
<p>Name {{ patientName }} </p>
```

But the problem is that you did not define `patientName` as an empty string in data. So there is no reactive property.

```
data(): {
    return {
        patientName: '',
    }
},
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `this` is not the issue. Data will print if we will use the data property with the `this` keyword.

Comment: You are right, that works, but I don't think it is good practice. You will not see the use of `this.` in a template in the Vue documentation.

Comment: Yes that's correct - It's not a good practice to access properties via `this` keyword in template.

Answer (score 0):

***Suggestions :***

- Please verify `response.data.message.patientName` is returning the patient name or not.
- In Template, You can access data properties directly by their names with out using `this` keyword. (It will not break anything if you will use that with `this` keyword as well)
- To make the property reactive, You should add that in your `data` method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    patientName: ''
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getPatientDetail();
  },
  methods: {
    getPatientDetail() {
      this.patientName =  'Alpha'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ this.patientName }}</p>
</div>
```